# Issues with exporting bootstrap modal

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I'm attempting to create a basic modal pulled directly from Bootstrap-React docs and i'm getting an export error.

I've attempted to refactor the initialization and exporting of the function, and still nothing.

```
import React from "react"
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal"
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button"
import useState from "react"

function Example() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
        Launch demo modal
      </Button>

      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

export default Example;
```

The issue that I'm getting is:

> TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...) is not a function

````
  4 | import useState from "react"
  5 | 
> 6 | function Example() {
  7 |   const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  8 | 
  9 |   const handleClose = () => setShow(false); ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because of this line,

```
import useState from "react"
```

You are trying to import `useState` as `default import`, but in `React` `useState` exported as `named export`.

It means, `useState` is exported something like this, ( Just example )

```
export const useState = () => { ... }
```

And you should import `useState` like this,

```
import { useState } from 'react'
```

Finally you can combine this import with your `React` import,

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
```

[Named Export vs Default Export in ES6](https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you didn't imported React.

try `import React, {useState} from "react"` instead of `import useState from "react"`

also make sure you have the right version of React. Since you're using Hooks it must be 16.8^